Proof that series of functions converges to a continuous function
I've been working through the exercises from Real Analysis: A Long-Form Textbook by Jay Cummings in my spare time, and am very close to finishing it! However, I've got stuck on a question which I can't quite figure out about series of functions. The question is as follows:
Prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{2}+x^{4}}{x^{2}+n^{4}}$ converges to some continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.
My issue with it is I don't know what type of convergence it means - pointwise or continuous? Either way, I still can't figure out how to prove it. Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated!

Should mean pointwise - note that each term of the sum is unbounded (and everywhere positive) as you increase $x$, acting like $x^2$, so uniform convergence can't be understood (convince yourself of this).

Thanks! Any idea how I'd go about proving that the limiting function is continuous then, as pw convergence doesn't preserve continuity? I'm assuming I'd have to find whatever this function is, no?

even if you don't have uniform convergence on the whole of $\mathbb R$ (which needs boundedness), you can argue uniform convergence on each bounded interval $[a, b]$. So you'll have continuity on each $[a, b]$ and so on the whole of $\mathbb R$. Unless I'm mistaken, the Weierstrass M-test should do fine for this, recalling that the sum of $1/n^2$ converges

Ah, I see, fantastic! I found that I was able to prove uniform convergence on any interval, but didn't think that it was possible to conclude that it was therefore continuous on all R. Don't know why, just seemed slightly scary.

every point is contained in some interval $[a, b]$! no worries, it's a neat subtlety
